# Se puede hacer una peticion ajax a esta url?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Me gustaría saber si puedo hacer una petición ajax a esta página web para descargarme videos de youtube, no lo consigo, en teoría con esto bastaría para que se descargara el archivo no?

```js
$(()=>{

  const api = 'http://youtubedl.xyz/download'
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  request.open('POST', api, true)

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  request.send('url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O09KF_abpdE')


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer ajax a dominios remotos, **solo** si tienen el header [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) que admita tu dominio o un wildcard como `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. O con navegadores previos a [estos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#Compatibilidad_del_Navegador). Porque es una restricción realizada por los navegadores. Si dicho servidor no tiene este header, o puedes pedir que lo agreguen o tendrás que descargar los videos desde un código del lado del servidor. Todo esto es porque los navegadores siguen la [Política del mismo origen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_del_mismo_origen). No existe otra manera con los navegadores mas usados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!
Pero entonces por que si guardo la página como html y hago la peticion desde el form del html si me deja? Eso solo es para peticiones ajax? porque entonces podría construirme un form oculto con jquery y submitearlo, así no habría problema creo...

Comment: @CarlosArroyo Claro, es solo para ajax, podrías hacer un form comun en HTML y mandarlo pero cuando das click en submit te vas a la otra pagina, eso no viola la politica de mismo origen. Si el action del form es de un mime no soportado por el navegador, lo descarga. Lo que puede pasar, según el navegador es que abra la otra pagina y se quede en blanco, o se hace la descarga y te mantiene en la página previa que sería la tuya

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!